# How to debug response recieved through PHP curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm new to PHP cURL. I tried the following code to send the request XML through URL.

```
xml_data =new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    error_log('http://www.test.com:8080/Rest/ContactServlet?request=' . urlencode($xml_data->asXML()));
    $xml_data = url_get_contents('http://www.test.com:8080/Rest/ContactServlet?request=' . urlencode($xml_data->asXML()));

}
function url_get_contents($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        error_log('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        return "error";
    } else {
        error_log('Operation completed without any errors');
        print_r($ch);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($output);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
     }
```

I'm now able to send the request XML to the web application successfully.
The Response XML has return status code like

```
<status>0</status> - Success
<status>1</status> - User already exists
```

But, even if I given unique names in form, I get the response as `"User already exists"` . If I try to insert the same request XML through URL, I get the `"Success"`. How can I debug this error. What is causing it to display `"User already exists"` instead of `"success"`.

Comment: How does the script, that generates the answer, look like?

Comment: @DainisAbols Sorry, I did not get you..

Comment: @DainisAbols The data is copied to `$xml_data`

Comment: You posted the `request` code. How does the code look like, that send the `response` ?

Comment: @DainisAbols I have tried only this...What should I add to get the response from the server